# Using Concurrent​Bag<​T> without allowing duplicates

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

I'm considering using Concurrent​Bag<​T> but I don't want to allow duplicates in my collection. My thinking goes that doing something like this will not be thread safe due to the "step" between checking and adding to the collection:

```
    private ConcurrentBag<IClientCallback> _callbackChannels = new ConcurrentBag<IClientCallback>();
...
    public void AddCallback(IClientCallback callback) {
        if (!_callbackChannels.Contains(callback))
        {
            _callbackChannels.Add(callback);
        }
    }
```

so I was thinking something like this, but maybe that's a terrible idea?

```
        _callbackChannels = new ConcurrentBag<IClientCallback>(_callbackChannels.Union(new List<IClientCallback>() { callback }));
```

So, my question is: Would this be thread safe-er than the check-add approach? Is there something I'm missing, is there an even better way?

The thinking is that multiple calls could theoretically happen to AddCallback with the same callback channel object - bad in itself, I know, but I want to handle it anyway.

Comment: Just use `ConcurrentDictionary<IClientCallback, object>`.

Comment: @gakera Have you considered using ConcurrentDictionary?

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary` is the way to go.

Comment: @Fabio hmm I hadn't thought of using it that way, that might be even better, thanks

Comment: Specifically, use `ConcurrentDictionary<IClientCallback, byte>` as this will also reduce allocations compared to using object as value.

Answer (score -3):

You can lock before adding into the bag.

```
private ConcurrentBag<IClientCallback> _callbackChannels = new ConcurrentBag<IClientCallback>();

 private object _lockObject = new Object();

    public void AddCallback(IClientCallback callback) 
    {
        lock(_lockObject)
        {
            if (!_callbackChannels.Contains(callback))
            {
                _callbackChannels.Add(callback);
            }
        }
    }
```

This might be expensive as each thread will wait at lock before earlier thread finishing the task.

Comment: Then you don't need `ConcurrentBag` and can just using `HashSet`

Comment: There's also no need for a second object, you can just lock on the collection itself

Comment: @Servy I was always taught to use explicit locking objects; isn't it considered bad form to lock the collection directly?  You obviously are more of an authority on this than I am though.

Comment: @BradleyUffner You shouldn't be locking on an object that's accessible from any larger scope than you need, or that is changing (unless you want to be changing what you're locking on).  If you don't have an object that won't change and that's suitably scoped (and it's common that you won't), then you create one.  If you already have one, then there's no reason to create *another*.